# can anyone solve this complex equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

$iz^6 + 2z^2 -2i = 0$

i'm really out of ideas. please help me.

Comment: This is not a nice question. The roots are messy. You just have to use the standard formula for the roots of a cubic (in $z^2$) and then take the square roots. Why do you want the answer? If you simply want the numerical answers use a standard package like WA.

Comment: i know this question is not well but it's my homework in university and it was really hard for me because i recently learn about complex numbers.i still think there should be a tricky way to solve this because otherwise there's no point in this question

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $z^2=u$ and solve for $u$ using Cardano's formula for cubic polynomials.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

Than take the two roots of each of the tree solutions.

Then, compare what you got to the results wolframalpha gives you.